# WPF: Switching DataTemplate for ListBox in Custom Control Changes ListBox.SelectedItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control that represents a "Pop Out" Menu. The control is a System.Windows.Controls.MultiSelector among other things.

The Control has a couple important dependency properties:

`Style: ListBoxStyle`

`Style: ItemContainerStyle`

`DataTemplate: ExpandedItemTemplate`

`DataTemplate: CollapsedItemTemplate`

`DataTemplate: CurrentItemTemplate (Readonly)`

`bool: IsExpanded`

The two DataTemplates show the user a different view for the items based on if the menu IsExpanded or not. Here they are:

```
        <Setter Property="ExpandedItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyItemIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding MyItemHeader}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="CollapsedItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding MyItemIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Content="{StaticResource MyItemIcon}"
                                  ToolTip="{Binding MyItemHeader}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Now, at this point the PopOut menu works just fine... the data items are initially bound correctly, switching between the expanded and collapsed menu state works perfectly, and everything is alright...

However, each of these DataTemplates sits inside a ListBoxItem inside the inner ListBox for the control. This ListBoxItem has a special "IsSelected" visual state that I want to make use of. So far, there is nothing telling the ListBoxItem when it should be selected or not. So I add this as my controls ItemContainerStyle (bound to the inner ListBox ItemContainerStyle):

```
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource MySpecialListBoxItemStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                            Value="{Binding MyItemIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

For reference, here is what the inner ListBox looks like in my custom controls ControlTemplate:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Style="{TemplateBinding ListBoxStyle}"
                 ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MyItems}"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"
                 ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type c:MyPopOutMenu}}, Path=CurrentItemTemplate}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

And inside the controls code, I have this method which sets the CurrentItemTemplate based on if the menu is expanded or not:

```
        private static void UpdateMenuItemTemplate(MyPopOutMenu menu, bool expanded)
        {
            if (expanded)
            {
                menu.SetValue(CurrentItemTemplatePropertyKey, menu.ExpandedItemTemplate);
            }
            else
            {
                menu.SetValue(CurrentItemTemplatePropertyKey, menu.CollapsedItemTemplate);
            }
        }
```

**Here is where the problem begins,** after adding the ItemContainerStyle that binds to the data items property that indicates if it should be selected "MyItemIsSelected", switching the DataTemplate: 'CurrentItemTemplate' will *change* the Selected Items on the inner ListBox.

In other words, the ListBox.SelectedItems property will (seemingly) randomly change if and only if I bind the ListBoxItem style to the data items property, and then switch the ListBoxes DataTemplate.

Its almost as if the ListBox control is internally keeping reference to different ListBoxItems (Item Containers) that correspond to each DataTemplate, and then when the DataTemplate is switched, it updates the TwoWay binding from stale ListBoxItems.

This is clearly a problem, as the control is changing application logic after a visual state change.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

I saw some advice on a different thread that said to use a CollectionView instead of binding the ItemsSource of the ListBox directly to the source collection. No luck there. Other advice said that the ListBox.IsSyncronizedWithCurrentItem property could help, also no luck there.

Comment: Is there any reason why your `ControlTemplate` binding for the `ItemTemplate` property uses FindAncestor instead of the `TemplateBinding` like the other properties do?

Comment: It is a readonly DependencyProperty that I am binding to there. I don't think you can use TemplateBinding with those although I could be wrong. Anyways, TemplateBinding is just syntax sugar for Binding RelativeSource FindAncestor

Comment: You cannot use `TemplateBinding` with readonly properties but because `TemplateBinding` is just a short-hand, limited way of saying  `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.  Specify the source that way and you can indeed bind to the parent properly.  I would make that change first and see if it has any effect.  Also are you getting any binding warnings in the output window?  Those might shed some light